# Hotfix entries in event log

Tags: windows-server-2008

Server 2008/2008 R2

I'm trying to remotely monitor these servers to watch the progress of hotfixes being installed.  I was able to find this in Server 2003/2003 R2:
-Log: System
-Source: NtServicePack

It seems the above event is written when every hotfix is installed.

I can't seem to find a comparable entry in Server 2008/2008 R2 though.  Is there anything similar that I can easily monitor for remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Server 2008, Once the Hotfix is installed , You should see the below event in `System` Logs

> Log Name:      System
>
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient
>
> Date:          12/19/2012 11:48:41 PM
>
> Event ID:      19
>
> Task Category: Windows Update Agent
>
> Level:         Information
>
> Keywords:      Success,Installation
>
> User:          SYSTEM
>
> Computer:      test123.abc.net
>
> Description:
>   Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Hotfix for Windows (KB2679255)

Event ID 19- should show you that the hotfix was installed successfully.
So I believe, `Windows Update Agent` is what you are looking for in comparison to Windows Server 2003